# How can I set a .`conf` to reference variables from a global `.env`

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, config

I have a `.conf` file that I want to reference a port number by an `env var` stored in a global  `.env` file.

Rough file structure looks something like:

```
|-.env
|
|-scripts/conf/my_conf.conf
```

I'd like to be able to set my variables like such:

**My .env**

```
HOST_PORT=7070
```

**My .conf**

```
webServicePort=${HOST_PORT}
```

However, in my `docker-compose.yml` I have a `healthcheck test` which never passes. Indicating that this port reference is not working. How can I set a .`conf` to reference a global `.env`